# Datatables lento

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Possuo uma base de dados com 5.985 registros. Estou usando o dataTables, mas ele demora muito para carregar.

É possível melhorar esse carregamento?

**Veja meu código:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table id="tabela-agenda" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Foto</th>
            <th>Badge</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th class="hidden-480">Telefone</th>
            <th class="hidden-480">Status</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <div class="visible-md visible-lg hidden-sm hidden-xs action-buttons">

                <?php if ($row_rs['badge'] != ""){?>
                <a class="purple" href="carteirinha.php?badge=<?php echo $row_rs['badge']; ?>" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, {objectType: 'iframe', width: 800, height:400 } )" title="Carteirinha"> <i class="icon-print bigger-130"></i> </a>
                <?php }?>

                <a class="blue" href="cadastroPerfil.php?id=<?php echo $row_rs['ID']; ?>&i=2a" title="Perfil"> <i class="icon-zoom-in bigger-130"></i> </a>
                <a class="green" href="cadastroEditar.php?id=<?php echo $row_rs['ID']; ?>&i=2a" title="Editar" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, {objectType: 'iframe', width: 800, height: 600 } )"> <i class="icon-pencil bigger-130"></i> </a>
                <a class="red delete-event" href="cadastroApagar.php?id=<?php echo $row_rs['ID']; ?>&foto=<?php echo $row_rs['foto']; ?>&i=2a" title="Apagar" data-title="Apagar" data-content="Deseja apagar esse membro?" onClick="return false;"> <i class="icon-trash bigger-130"></i> </a> </div>
              <div class="visible-xs visible-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                <div class="inline position-relative">
                  <button class="btn btn-minier btn-yellow dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="icon-caret-down icon-only bigger-120"></i> </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-only-icon dropdown-yellow pull-right dropdown-caret dropdown-close">
                    <li> <a href="#" class="tooltip-info" data-rel="tooltip" title="Ver"> <span class="blue"> <i class="icon-zoom-in bigger-120"></i> </span> </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#" class="tooltip-success" data-rel="tooltip" title="Editar"> <span class="green"> <i class="icon-edit bigger-120"></i> </span> </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#" class="tooltip-error" data-rel="tooltip" title="Apagar"> <span class="red"> <i class="icon-trash bigger-120"></i> </span> </a> </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript que carrega:**

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var oTable1 = $('#tabela-agenda').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "cadastroCarregaRegistros.php",
    columns: [{
        data: "foto", //Nome do campo no JSON, que contem a url da foto
        render: function(value) {
          return '<img src="/images/fotos/' + value + '" height="50" alt=""/>';
        }
      },
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      {
        data: "status", //Nome do campo no JSON, retorna o status do cadastro
        render: function(value) {
          switch (value) {
            case "N":
              return '<span class="label label-warning">Aguardando aprovação</span>';
              break;
            case "A":
              return '<span class="label label-success">Ativo</span>';
              break;
            case "V":
              return '<span class="label label-danger">Vencido</span>';
              break;
            case "B":
              return '<span class="label label-inverse">Banido</span>';
              break;
            case "FP":
              return '<span class="label label-purple">Falta Pagar</span>';
              break;
          }
        }
      },
      null
    ]
  });

</script>
```

**cadastroCarregaRegistros.php**

```
<?php
    /*
     * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and MySQL
     * Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine
     * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
     */
    
    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */
    
    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
     * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
     */
    $aColumns = array('ID', 'foto', 'badge', 'nome', 'email', 'tel_celu', 'status' );
    
    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "ID";
    
    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "cadastro";
    
    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = "";
    $gaSql['password']   = "";
    $gaSql['db']         = "";
    $gaSql['server']     = "localhost";
    
    
    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
     * no need to edit below this line
     */
    
    /* 
     * MySQL connection
     */
    $gaSql['link'] =  mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) or
        die( 'Could not open connection to server' );
    
    mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) or 
        die( 'Could not select database '. $gaSql['db'] );
    
    
    /* 
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }
    
    
    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
            }
        }
        
        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }
    
    
    /* 
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }
    
    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }
    
    
    /*
     * SQL queries
     * Get data to display
     */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";
    $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    
    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];
    
    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];
    
    
    /*
     * Output
     */
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );
    
    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }
    
    $obj = json_encode( $output );
    echo $obj;
?>
```

Comment: Não depende so dá biblioteca, depende também do servidor que disponibiliza os dados

Comment: Tem como fazer cache ou algo a mais para melhorar? O que poder ser feito será bem vindo.

Comment: Se estiver pegando de um BD e for uma tabela acessada com certa freqüência, pode fazer uma _view_ da consulta.

Comment: Velho, posta a sua Query de Consulta? Ou explica a regra de negocio desse modulo, talvez fique mais fácil pra te uxiliar

Comment: Eu utilizo, com cerca de 100 mil registros, e não me parece nada lento, qual server-side está usando ?

Comment: Seu código e query parecem Ok... o problema deve ser o servidor mesmo

Comment: Obrigado a todos, atualizei o post com meu código completo.

Comment: Porque você não usa a paginação nativa do DataTables para exibir paginas de 10 em 10 registros, ou de 100 em 100, por exemplo? Eu utilizo assim para milhares de registros e é super rapido, porém você tem que implementar isso server-side, mas vale a pena! De uma olhada aqui; http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html

Comment: @renatoargh qual o comando js para fazer como esta informando?

Comment: Vi o link, mas não entendi como usar.

Comment: Você está usando todos os campos com o `SELECT *` ? Se a tabela tiver muitos campos, prefira especificar as colunas que realmente precise.

Comment: @Earendul Verdade, esqueci desse detalhe. Vou fazer agora e ver como vai ficar.

Comment: Fiz, mas ainda demora. A página demorou 273 segundos para carregar.

Comment: Limita tambem aquantidade de registros que vem do banco: ´LIMIT 0,1;´

Comment: Tiago, da uma olhada na minha resposta!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tiago, da maneira que você está fazendo o que acontece é o seguinte;

1. Você faz um request no servidor
2. Você busca todos os 5k registros no banco de dados
3. Você renderiza um HTML gigantesco com todos os milhares de registros
4. O browser recebe os dados e gasta muito tempo aplicando a DataTables em todos esses registros

**Primeiro gargalo:** Item 3 - O trafego de tantos dados pode estar aumentando o tempo até que a página fique pronta

**Segundo gargalo:** Item 4 - O tempo para aplicar o DataTables provavelmente esta tornando 90% deste tempo.

*PS.: Possível gargalo no item 2 dependendo de como a sua aplicação esta implantada*

O fato é, muito dificilmente o usuário vai consumir 5k registros todas as vezes que abrir a sua página, portanto a melhor abordagem na minha opinião é;

1. Você recebe um request e devolve uma página basicamente vazia, contendo apenas a estrutura da tabela HTML vazia, onde voce vai aplicar o DataTables
2. Assim que o browser receber o HTML e a página estiver pronta (em `$(function() {});` por exemplo) você chama o DataTables passando os parâmetros para utilizar a paginação nativa deles, ou seja:

```
$('table.dataTable').DataTable({
    displayLength: 15, //Começaremos com apenas 15 registros
    serverSide: true,  //Quem vai tratar a interação com a tabela é o servidor
    paginate: true,    //Queremos paginas
    filter: true,      //Queremos que o usuário possa procurar entre os 5k registros
    ajax: {
        url: 'filtragemDeRegistros.php' //O seu script que vai filtrar os dados do lado do servidor
    }
});
```

Acontece que agora você precisa implementar a lógica de filtragem no backend. Para você descobrir quais parâmetros o DataTables passa para o servidor você pode pesquisar a documentação na pagina oficial do DT ou simplesmente imprimir no console do servidor o request enviado.

Voce vai gastar um tempinho implementando mas vale a pena e a app vai carregar muito mais rápida.

Ps.: A doc do datatables ensina detalhadamente tudo isso, gaste um tempo lendo!

**EDIT** Um exemplo de processamento server side retirado diretamente da [documentação do DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html):

```
<?php
 
/*
 * DataTables example server-side processing script.
 *
 * Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simply to show how
 * server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as
 * the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as
 * for learning.
 *
 * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
 * side processing requirements of DataTables.
 *
 * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
 */
 
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */
 
// DB table to use
$table = 'datatables_demo';
 
// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';
 
// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'first_name', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'last_name',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'position',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'office',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'start_date',
        'dt'        => 4,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return date( 'jS M y', strtotime($d));
        }
    ),
    array(
        'db'        => 'salary',
        'dt'        => 5,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return '$'.number_format($d);
        }
    )
);
 
// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => '',
    'host' => ''
);
 
 
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */
 
require( 'ssp.class.php' );
 
echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

**EDIT**:

Para usar o render para gerar uma imagem você vai precisar colocar um campo "columns":

```
var oTable1 = $('#tabela-agenda').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "cadastroCarregaRegistros.php",
    columns: [
        {
            data: "foto", //Nome do campo no JSON, que contem a url da foto
            render: function(value) {
                return '<img src="http://seuendereco.com/imagens/' + value + '"/>';
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

**OBS:** Substitua o `src` da imagem adequadamente.

Eu acho que voce vai precisar definir um objeto desse para cada coluna, não sei se você pode emitir o resto. faz o teste com isso que sugeri e me responde lá no chat

Comment: Muito obrigado por essas instruções, só mais uma coisa, que código fica dentro do filtragemDeRegistros.php?

Comment: Tiago, o código que fica dentro do `.php` é um codigo especifico para que voce faça a filtragem dos dados no banco de dados, eu não sei php mas na propria página do DT tem um exemplo em php: http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html logo embaixo da tabela de exemplo tem varias abas; "JavaScript", "HTML", ...., "Server Side script". Clica em server side script e esta la o exemplo. Eu vou editar a resposta com o exemplo tambem...

Comment: Depois de muito custo, estou conseguindo... kkkk. O código já gera o json para puxar no ajax e já mostra na tabela. Mas 3 colunas que não estou sabendo manipular. Colocar a imagem, colocar o switch, e mostrar os comandos da ultima coluna. Como fazer isso?

Comment: A imagem eu passo a url como um campo do json, ex.: `{ imagem: 'http://imagem.com' }` e ai eu uso a [propriedade render da coluna](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) para renderizar um `img`, fica assim: `render: function(imagem) { return '<img src="' + imagem + '"/>'; }` - para essa geração dinamica de HTML eu uso o [Pithy](https://github.com/caolan/pithy)

Comment: O que você quer dizer com switch exatamente?

Comment: Veja um exemplo do switch, antes eu fazia assim porque vinha da Query mysql, http://i.imgur.com/3B3AxF4.png

Comment: Saquei, vc tb vai usar um `render` pra isso. Me diz uma coisa, vc conseguiu fazer a imagem?

Comment: Aimigão, vou ser franco, estou fazendo mas sem nenhuma noção do que estou fazendo...rsrs. Estou usando (http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysqli), como usar esse `render`? Como mostrar a imagem no campo que eu preciso, pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: Imagem da minha tabela http://i.imgur.com/gkdsJs9.png. Na primeira coluna deveria aparecer as imagem, no status o switch, e na ultima os comandos editar excluir...

Comment: Ta no caminho certo!!! Faz assim, edita a sua pergunta com o novo código do datatables que voce ta usando. Você consegue entrar no chat aqui do SOpt? Comentarios grandes nao sao encorajados aqui no SO...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19155/discussion-between-renatoargh-and-tiago).

Comment: Estou no chat @renatoargh